# How can I stop NLog from double logging

Tags: c#, nlog

I'm writing a WEB API call for NLog, so remote apps can log to my logging table.

In my controller I have (hard-coded for now as a sanity check):

```
NLogger.LogError("Some Error Message", "An exception", 5, "A computer name");
```

Then my static LogError method looks like this (I tried LogEventInfo() too):

```
public static void LogError(string msg, string ex, int appid, string machineName)
{
    LogEventInfo logEvent = new LogEventInfo(LogLevel.Error, "Api Logger", "Another test msg");
    logEvent.Properties["myMsg"] = msg;
    logEvent.Properties["myEx"] = ex;
    logEvent.Properties["myAppId"] = appid;
    logEvent.Properties["myMachineName"] = machineName;
    NLogManager.Instance.Log(logEvent);
}
```

Lastly, this is my code first config for that rule (there's 2 others with different db targets):

```
private static void ConfigureApiLog()
{
    var dbApiErrorTarget = new DatabaseTarget
    {
        ConnectionString = ConnectionFactory.GetSqlConnection().ConnectionString,
        CommandText = "usp_LogError",
        CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    };

    dbApiErrorTarget.Parameters.Add(new DatabaseParameterInfo("@level",
        new global::NLog.Layouts.SimpleLayout("${level}")));
    dbApiErrorTarget.Parameters.Add(new DatabaseParameterInfo("@logger",
        new global::NLog.Layouts.SimpleLayout("${logger}")));
    dbApiErrorTarget.Parameters.Add(new DatabaseParameterInfo("@message",
        new global::NLog.Layouts.SimpleLayout("${event-properties:item=myMsg}")));
    dbApiErrorTarget.Parameters.Add(new DatabaseParameterInfo("@exception",
        new global::NLog.Layouts.SimpleLayout("${event-properties:item=myEx}")));
    dbApiErrorTarget.Parameters.Add(new DatabaseParameterInfo("@AppId",
        new global::NLog.Layouts.SimpleLayout("${event-properties:item=myAppId}")));
    dbApiErrorTarget.Parameters.Add(new DatabaseParameterInfo("@MachineName",
        new global::NLog.Layouts.SimpleLayout("${event-properties:item=myMachineName}")));

    Config.AddTarget("database", dbApiErrorTarget);

    Config.LoggingRules.Add(new LoggingRule("*", LogLevel.Error, LogLevel.Fatal, dbApiErrorTarget));
}
```

I expect 1 log per log call to the logger instance, but I'm getting two and I'm not exactly sure why:

```
   Id   Date    Level   Logger  Message Exception   AppId   MachineName
1   2017-03-03 22:43:20.557 Error   Api Logger  Another test msg        0   mylocalmachine
2   2017-03-03 22:43:20.603 Error   Api Logger  Some Error Message  An exception    5   A computer name
```

AppId 0 is my Api, 5 is some remote app, hard coded at this point as POC.

Might be that it's Friday, but I can't seem to figure out what's wrong with the code.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Check if `Config.LoggingRules` contains any other rules.  I bet it does.

Comment: Yea it did, turns out they're cumulative: http://nlog-forum.1685105.n2.nabble.com/Log-generated-twice-in-logfile-td4682750.html .  I guess the rules aren't target specific like I thought (why do I pass them my target then).  Feel free to post as answer and I'll accept it to mark the question as closed.  I set the troublesome rule to log error min max and the other to log fatal min max, which fixed my issue, not ideal, but I'll probably make a custom level later for the Api.

Comment: Rules *can* be target specific.  Configuring through the XML the rule has the `writeTo` property, with a comma separated list of targets.  You can also omit that property, and it writes to all targets.  I'm less familiar with the API configuration, but its probably analogous.  The default rules will likely write to all targets.

Comment: I thought that's what this line did: Config.LoggingRules.Add(new LoggingRule("*", LogLevel.Error, LogLevel.Fatal, dbApiErrorTarget)) there doesn't seem to be a 5th param I can pass in either on the overloads.  Guess I was wrong, or it's buggy.  I'll try the clear since the execution path of the API call should only care about my custom LogEventInfo.

Comment: I can't really answer that due to my lack of familiarity with the NLog configuration API.  I've always used the XML config.  (hint: you can format code in comments using backticks, like:  `\`hi\`` )

Comment: I don't think a default rule was in play here, the offending rule was one of my internal logging rules:  Config.LoggingRules.Add(new LoggingRule("*", LogLevel.Error, LogLevel.Fatal, dbErrorTarget)); became Config.LoggingRules.Add(new LoggingRule("*", LogLevel.Error, LogLevel.Error, dbErrorTarget)); and Config.LoggingRules.Add(new LoggingRule("*", LogLevel.Error, LogLevel.Fatal, dbApiErrorTarget)); became Config.LoggingRules.Add(new LoggingRule("*", LogLevel.Fatal, LogLevel.Fatal, dbApiErrorTarget));

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rules in NLog *can* be target specific, or it can write to *all* targets.  The default rule(s) won't have any targets specified, so they will write to any you create.  You're also adding your own rule, which writes specifically to your target and no others.

Thus, the double-logging.

You can remove the default rules to resolve the issue.

```
Config.LoggingRules.Clear();
```

before you add your rule.

Answer (score 10):

I had this problem and found the problem, for my specific case. Problem was double entries everywhere on every target.

I had a .NET Core web application which used the UseNLog() inside the Program.cs IWebHostBuilder. This performs AddNLog() internally.
Then in the startup I manually did loggerInstance.AddNLog() which caused the dual insertion.

The latter must be removed since UseNLog is a far better and "sooner" time to enable NLog

Hope it helps!